# Conectar Firebird via PHP

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, firebird

Tenho um BD em Firebird em um servidor diferente do servidor web(PHP).
Estou tentando fazer a conexão entre eles, usando a função ibase_connect, porém nada acontece, minha linha no php é: `$dbh=ibase_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(ibase_errcode());` e em seguida `echo "teste";` e não acontece a exibição do "teste" nem mensagem de erro.

Tenho no servidor web as dlls do firebird e a php_interbase.dll

Preciso de ajuda para realizar essa conexão.

Seguindo as recomendações, descobri que a extensão do PHP estava ativa na instância errado no ISS. Consegui ligar na instância correta e apareceu a mensagem de erro `connection rejected by remote interface`. Acredito que o erro agora é conseguir mapear o endereço do BD Firebird.

Comment: O PHP reconheceu o interbase? Para verificar isso, execute a função phpinfo() e vê se há o interbase.

Comment: Identificou sim, aparece na tabela Module Authors, | InterBase | Jouni Ahto, Andrew Avdeev, Ard Biesheuvel |

Comment: Verifica se tem algo parecido como nessa imagem: https://i.imgur.com/779oPmB.png O que você falou apenas é os autores do módulo e não significa que foi reconhecido. Caso não tiver, a conexão com o firebird não está pegando pois o PHP não está reconhecendo.

Comment: Isso não apareceu não, nesse caso é erro no driver?

Comment: Na verdade, o PHP não reconheceu o módulo interbase e então não irá conseguir fazer a comunicação. Você está utilizando Wamp ou outro servidor?

Comment: Isso já não sei te dizer (mas acho que não é Wamp), eu já saí do trabalho hoje. Na segunda feira eu vejo e coloco aqui.

Comment: Bom dia @Piupz

Recebi uma recomendação de colocar o código 
'ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);'
 para exibir o erro que está ocorrendo, e foi o seguinte: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in C:\VRE\AvCIPES\PHP\ConectFire.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\VRE\AvCIPES\PHP\ConectFire.php on line 11

Sobre o servidor, aparece apenas com o nome "Server Manager" da Microsoft, eu desconheço sobre o Wamp.

Comment: Nunca realizei conexão com o firebird via php, mas normalmente em aplicações desktop é necessário colocar as dlls `gds32.dll` e `fbclient.dll` na mesma pasta onde está o executável, tente por as mesmas junto com seu arquivo de conexão php.

Comment: Consegui realizar a conexão, mas está muito intermitente e inclusive está “derrubando” o banco. Existe uma outra aplicação que as pessoas usam esse mesmo banco, quando eu começo a testar, essa outra aplicação começa a falhar.